# Will destroying masterfully decorated items cause bad thoughts for the decorator?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a bunch of low quality cages sitting around and I'd like to melt them down; however, my bone carver has gotten his hands on a few, of which he has masterfully decorated.

Will melting these masterfully-decorated cages cause a bad thought for the bone carver who did the decorating?

Comment: I get anouncements when low-quality cloth item from masterwork cloth is destroyed. I don't know if it is causes bad thought, because previos weaver is dead. I think this will also happen with decorations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destroying masterfully-decorated items **does** cause a bad thought in the dwarf who did the decorating.

I went ahead and designated the cages in question for melting, and once they had been melted I received notification:

```
A masterwork of Urist McDecorator has been lost!
```

And the dwarf who had done the decorating had a bad thought:

```
She feels hopeless after suffering the travesty of art defacement.
```

Comment: Looks like you figured it out before I could answer, but for future reference, the likelihood of an unhappy thought from art defacement decreases when the number of masterworks the dwarf has made increases.